# zsh can't see and doesn't load the ~/.zshrc startup file

Tags: command-line, zsh, file-extensions

After upgrading to Catalina and encountering the zsh upgrade reminder when launching Terminal, I've decided to switch to zsh.

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

However, I'm having trouble getting Terminal/zsh to recognize the `.zshrc` startup file located in my home folder. `~/zshrc` isn't loaded on launch, and executing `source ~/.zshrc` returns `source: no such file or directory`.

The file only contains one line, an alias tying `python` to `python3`.

[image: Finder showing .zshrc presence next to an open TextEdit window of the file]
[image: Terminal showing the lack of any aliases and the failed source command]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that `.zshrc` had a hidden `.txt` file extension. Somehow it was automatically named `.zshrc.txt`, probably when I used TextEdit to edit it, and `source` doesn't infer the text extension. Finder also doesn't display the `.txt` extension by default unless you inspect the file, so I hadn't noticed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similarly, my terminal/zsh wasn't recognizing my .zshrc file also, so running `source ~/.zshrc` helped me find that my zshrc file was formatted improperly (it contained spaces before/after an equals symbol in `alias g="git"`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to @chinookf. My `.zshenv` had a typo in the declaration of a `function`, which was causing both `.zshenv` and `.zshrc` to not load properly.
As simple as removing a space in the `function` declaration and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the thing was hidden in the line `To update your account to use zsh, please run chsh -s /bin/zsh.`

As I understood, the problem is in fact, that for any reason zsh was not a default shell interpreter in the system after a fresh update to macOS Sonoma. After execution of `chsh -s /bin/zsh` - the issue with "ignored" `.zshrc` disappeared.